# Automating Deployment Environment Ansible based on hostname (nested variable name)

Tags: ansible

Using an ansible playbook, I have three stages of development aka. test stage prod and want to access a dictionary with settings based on the stages. My ./defaults/main.yaml would have:

```
prod:
  proxy_url: prod.example.com

stage:
  proxy_url: stage.example.com

test:
  proxy_url: test.example.com
```

I set a custom fact based on the machine hostname. As a convention I use the stage as a postfix like `app1-test`

```
- set_fact: deployment="{{ ansible_hostname.split('-')[-1] | lower }}"
```

This creates the fact deployment as `test` like so:

```
"{{ deployment }}"
```

Now when I want to access my variables this works:

```
"{{ test['proxy_host'] }}"
```

But this not:

```
"{{ (deployment)['proxy_host'] }}"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Way too complicated. Put your hosts into three groups and set the proxy in the group vars.

Comment: *What am I missing?* that `deployment` is one level of indirection away from what you want; thus: `{{ vars[deployment]["proxy_host"] }}`

Comment: @ceving I am creating a generic role for foreman so I can not build an inventory with host groups and it is a requirement that the stage is fetched from the hostname. But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Do not put "solved" in the subject. Post solution as regular answer and mark it accepted (even if it is yours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution thanks to @mdaniel:

```
{{ vars[deployment]["proxy_host"] }}
```